# How to limit time when SELECTing (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table in database and a column named `timedate` the time is stored like this in this column: `2013-05-25 12:15:25`

I need to `SELECT` the row with the time within last 15 minutes only; so in the case above

> *SELECT if timedate is after `2013-05-25 12:00:25`*

I tried:

`TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS('timedate') < 15`

but it didn't work

```
SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    `column` 
  WHERE 
    `name` = 'name' 
    AND `family` = 'family'  
    AND (
      `test1` = 'test1 value' 
      || `test2` = 'test2 value' 
      || `test3` = 'test3 value' 
    ) 
    AND TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS('timedate') < 15 
  LIMIT 
    1
```

Comment: MySQL TO_DAYS() returns number of days between a given date and year 0

Comment: You might be interested in reading: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/367456)

Comment: There is no `E_DOESNT_WORK` in PHP. You have to explain by what criteria you determined that it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `column` 
WHERE `name` = {$name} 
AND `family` = {$family}  
AND (`test1` = {$test1} || `test2` = {$test2} || `test3` = {$test3}) 
AND `timedate` > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

**Important**: Note that I replaced your `'` around timedate with backticks. With `'` MySQL thinks it's a string, not a column name.

Answer (score 1):

If type of field `test1`, `test2` and `test3` is number, then your query should be :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `column` 
WHERE `name` = '{$name}' 
  AND `family` = '{$family}'
  AND (
    `test1` = {$test1} || `test2` = {$test2} || `test3` = {$test3}
  ) 
  AND ADDTIME(`timedate`, '00:15:00.000000') > NOW()
```

And if type of field `test1`, `test2` and `test3` is varchar, your query should be :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `column` 
WHERE `name` = '{$name}' 
  AND `family` = '{$family}'
  AND (
    `test1` = '{$test1}' || `test2` = '{$test2}' || `test3` = '{$test3}'
  ) 
  AND ADDTIME(`timedate`, '00:15:00.000000') > NOW()
```

Hopefully this help.

Comment: thanks but why number or varchar for type of field? the type is datetime

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is field test1, test2 and test3. I update the answer. Also please enclose {$name} and {$family} with '. :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

You can use `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15:00 MINUTE_SECOND)` to get the time 15 minutes ago, and then compare the dates with the `>` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TIMESTAMPDIFF (MINUTE, NOW(), timestamp)`

See [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`timedate`) < 15 FROM ......
```

Comment: i don't think this will work, as the output is like 46:58:57.999999 it will work for hours not minutes